# What does "quarry goes to ground, leave no ground to go to" mean?

Tags: meaning

In Serenity (2005), the Operative speaks to Malcolm, who lost his friends:

> Operative: **If your quarry goes to ground, leave no ground to go to**.
> You should have taken my offer. Or did you think none of this was your
> fault?

What does "quarry goes to ground, leave no ground to go to" mean?

**I have two interpretations**:

What I think the Operative means is that if the place you thought you belonged
to turned out to be a wrong place, then do not hesitate about never going back there.

(or)

Quarry goes to the ground : the business is ruined |
No ground to go to : All possible actions to restart the business or
start some other business will be impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *quarry* is the creature you are hunting; if it *goes to ground*, it hides in its burrow, so you need to leave it nowhere to hide. Presumably the Operative is using the expression in a metaphorical sense.